# Indexing on multiple fields for filtering and range query

Tags: indexing, data-structures, nosql

I was trying to build an in-memory indexing structure for all fields in my data so that I can have efficient access. Suddenly I realize that this may already be an important requirement for NoSQL im-memory databases such as MongoDB, Cassandra, or Memcached. Therefore I want to know if there exists mature ways of solving my problem.

According to my understanding, most NoSQL databases arrange data in the format of key-value pairs, or key-key-value pairs. This was efficient for accessing specific data points.

1. However, if I want to perform a lot of range queries, did NoSQL databases have indexing techniques that can efficiently handle those queries?
2. In addition, let's say I have 100 fields in my sales data, and how to efficiently handle queries that require multiple filters? E.g., one filter for id, another for a range of dates, and another for price range. Did NoSQL database already provide such functionalities?

Thanks for all your inputs.